# TCP connection with TLS reset after handshake

Tags: c#, wcf, tls1.2

I'm trying to activate transport security for a WCF Client-Server application.
It works fine on our test machine, but in the target environment the connection is always reset after what looks to me like a successful handshake:
[Wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d057c.png)

I've tried deactivating the firewall, although the application worked fine without TLS, but it made no difference. I've also tried TLS1.1 and TLS1.0 but that made no difference either.

Here is the source code for the service host:

```
public void Start()
{
    var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
    binding.Security.Transport.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
    binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
    binding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 64 * 1048576;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;

    this.host = new ServiceHost(
        this,
        new[] { new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}", this.hostname, this.port)) }
    );

    this.host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
    this.host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
    this.host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ILvsService), binding, "LvsService");
    this.host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
        StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
        StoreName.My,
        X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
       this.hostname
    );

    this.host.Open();
}
```

And here is the client side:

```
public ServiceClient(string server, ushort port)
{
    var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
    binding.Security.Transport.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 64 * 1048576;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    var context = new InstanceContext(this);
    this.channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<ILvsService>(
        context,
        binding,
        new EndpointAddress(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/LvsService", server, port))
    );
}
```

The server is running as a service on a Windows Server 2016 VM with .NET Framework 4.7.2. The clients are running on Windows 10 machines also with .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client

Comment: Maybe you can try changing SecurityMode from Transport to Message on both client and service, you can take a look at the answer provided by [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/921d1a34-ba28-4371-b46a-2c849c45dadb/wcf-nettcp-with-ssltls-fails-during-handshake-server-resets-the-connection?forum=wcf).